# magento 2 workflow and folder structure

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I am very new to magento.

I had just install `magento 2.1` and follow user guide but I am not understanding the workflow and folder structure.

I am also trying to understand luma theme (debug mode on). but unable to find structure.

Is there any documentation to understand the workflow and folder structure of magento 2?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get an idea of the module structure from here : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/magento2/4838/module-structure#t=201612190905489831985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/) is the place to be. If you focus mainly on frontend development, take the [Frontend Developer Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html). And if you really want to get a feel for the system and design philosophy, I recommend that you take an hour to really read the introduction and conventions through and not just skip to the snippets.

Comment: If he's really very new to Magento I suggest he takes a month to get to know Magento before expecting to do any productive work. It's what I did, basically just work towards getting the Developer or the Frontend certifications. It's too complicated a system to just start working with it in a day.